# Apache - ProxyPassReverse multiple entries with same host

Tags: reverse-proxy, proxypass

we have apache load balancing configuration like so:

```
<Proxy balancer://acluster>
BalancerMember ajp://10.10.10.1:8123 route=r1
BalancerMember ajp://10.10.10.2:8123 route=r2
</Proxy>
ProxyPass / balancer://acluster

#ProxyPassReverse / balancer://acluster
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://10.10.10.1:8123
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://10.10.10.2:8123
```

I am trying to find out, what is the purpose or effect of having those multiple ProxyPassReverse entries instead of using that line which was commented out.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR: Just use the `ProxyPassReverse / balancer://acluster`.

There is no purpose with those separate `ProxyPassReverse` lines as the [Apache Module mod_proxy_balancer](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html) gives [example configuration](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_balancer.html#example) with `ProxyPassReverse` referencing the `balancer://`:

> ```
> <Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
>     BalancerMember "http://192.168.1.50:80"
>     BalancerMember "http://192.168.1.51:80"
> </Proxy>
> ProxyPass        "/test" "balancer://mycluster"
> ProxyPassReverse "/test" "balancer://mycluster"
> ```

The documentation for [`ProxyPassReverse` Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse) does not specify what would happen with multiple `ProxyPassReverse` directives. In the worst-case, requests for a balancer member might have the rewritten `Host` header of another balancer member. It depends on the configuration of the backend server whether this causes problems or not.

Also, if the current configuration with separate lines was valid, it would not be an easily manageable solution as it would require an additional update for the `ProxyPassReverse` configuration every time you add a `BalancerMember`.

Comment: Thank you, i was thinking that its maybe so the request made via reverseProxy do not go through the cluster. Its a strange one